# Customize AWS Cognito registering message to API developer portal

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, portal

I'm switching AWS API Developer portal registration to invite-only mode. Developer portal Self-service Sign-up  can be disabled from Amazon Cognito > User pools > User pool > Sign-up experience tab. When this is done portals register-link shows a message:

> An error was encountered with the requested page.
>
> > Signup is not allowed.

How those messages can be customized? I'd like to tell to the user to contact admin to get a new account.

[image: default message]